# Trying to update urls in Django but keep getting errors

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I want to make my urls more descriptive for SEO purposes.

I want to add session variables and database variables, however neither seems to be working.

path was:

```
path('thing/<int:pk>'...)
```

trying to change to:

```
path('thing/<str:db_varible>/<int:pk>'...)
```

and trying to change to:

```
path('thing/<str:local_session_variable>/<int:pk>'...)
```

I'm keep getting the NoReverseMatch error.

Comment: It needs ending up with a `/` of path.

Comment: it doesn't, the first path works.

Comment: what is the url called in browser?